# Apache mod_rewrite not working even trying different solutions:

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying to shorten URLs with apache .htaccess file, and currently I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ show.php?page=$1 [NC, QSA, L]
AllowOverride All
```

With this code, for example `https://example.com/welcome` should be redirected to `https://example.com/show.php?page=welcome`, but it is not. When I run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, I get the following:

> Module rewrite already enabled

I also tried to run service apache2 restart. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you enabled the consideration of such distributed configuration files _at all_ ? See the `AllowOverride` directive for your http host. If you have, then what does your http server's error log file contain? Any hint in there? If not, try coding a definite syntax error in your configuration file. Do you _then_ get a corresponding error or not?

Comment: The code you've posted is syntactically invalid. So, if you are not getting a 500 Internal Server Error then the `.htaccess` file is not being processed at all.  (`AllowOverride All` must go in the server config, not `.htaccess`.) Once you've got `.htaccess` files being processed then you can fix your rule.